# Debugging an application in VS works, but running the application doesnt, why?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

What i mean is that i have a VS project. The project compiles and links properly. When i click on "Start Debugging", the application runs and everything seems to be working.

When i go to the debug or release directory and try to run the application, I get a runtime error. Why does this happen?

I dont know how to word this to search in Google. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you are gettin?

Comment: Debug Assertion Failed! Program: ...  File: fgets.c Line:57 Expression: ( str != NULL ). I think its because fgets is getting a null pointer to a file. Anyway, what i would like to understand is why clicking on "Start Debugging" i dont encounter this problem?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET app, WinForms app, Console app, or what? How are you trying to run it? Double-clicking on a file? We need to know a lot more to be able to help... For example, some people try double-clicking on an ASPX file because they don't get that it needs to be hosted in IIS (or Cassini) and can't be run directly from the file system. There are so many variables here that we can't possibly answer this question.

Comment: It is a windows application. Yeah, i am trying to run it by double clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

debuggers often do extra initialization of variables that otherwise will not occur at runtime. Or you debug environment includes a dependency that is not available when you run it independently of VS

Comment: How can i emulate the VS debugging enviroment when running the application independently?

Comment: check your start > programs > Visual Studio XXXX folder or subfolders for a command line shortcut. Typically it will open a dos prompt window with the path and other settings for running visual studio. type 'set' at the dos prompt to see all the settings